# Dynamically importing modules into a angular2 app

Tags: ajax, angular

Assuming the scenario where there are two angular 2 apps each with a Java developed back-end (app-1 and app-2) deployed in different packages.

Is it possible to make a ajax call from app 1 and based on the data retrieved by that ajax call to load into app 1 modules from app 2 using a Ajax call or something?

If yes, how would that work?

Example:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AppService }     from './shared/app.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [AppService]
})
export class AppComponent{

constructor(private appService: AppService){}

ngOnInit(){
    let test = this.appService.checkUserPrivileges();
    if(test.length > 1){
        // make ajax calls that retrieves modules based on the test data
        // inject ajax retrieved modules into module that contains the component somehow
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What module do you want to load dynamically , why can't you add it already